# Does adding bounty increase the number of views?

Tags: discussion

Is there any data whether adding bounty really increase the number of views ?

I feel number of views does not increase even after adding bounty ?

Data required is number of views after adding bounty to particular question and its previous number of views.

Is there any data for this ?

Comment: I am not sure if such data exists, but in my opinion, it's all dependent on users type. For example, in case users search the `featured` tab for a try to increase their `reputation` then it might help increase the number of views (as long as they didn't see it before, if this is taken into account), but if users doesn't really care about the `reputation` and they surf the site for some fun and some challenge, then it won't really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I do not have access to the data requested.

However, I do think that I can answer your question.

The point of bounties is **not** to necessarily increase views, as implied in your question. Rather, it is an incentive for viewers to actually answer the question instead of passing it over.

Think of it this way: I offer a bounty on an unanswered question with, say, 200 views. If, when the bounty expires, the question has 2,000 views and no correct answers, then the bounty did not serve its purpose. If, on the other hand, the question is answered and has no additional views, then the bounty *did* serve its purpose - it gave a previous viewer the incentive to add some extra effort into answering the question.

Sometimes the answer-er is a new viewer, sometimes not. Sometimes the bounty increases views; sometimes not. Occasionally, the bounty is even placed simply as an award to an already-given answer.

**TL;DR** Bounties are supposed to increase answers, not views.

Comment: I think that this explains it perfectly. Nice job, mate.